# Remove sorting arrows from Sorted header in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have many sorted columns in y report and the little arrows are causing the report to become super wide.  I need the columns to stay sortable, but I gotta get rid of those sorting arrows. Ideas?

Comment: Did you figure it out or are you still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
Check the **padding** of each textbox by default it is set to 2pt (for left, right, top and bottom). **Reduce it to 0pt** for all the textboxes (sorted and unsorted). This will save some space.

**Step 2**
After reducing the padding if report is still wide. **Split the header** in multiple lines. If your header is *Here is the Data* split it into multi lines to make some space. 
*Here is 

 the Data* 
**Reduce the font size of header.**

**Step 3**
If the report is still wide then try this:
**Create parameters to handle sorting**. Create two parameters "Sort By" and "Sort Order". "Sort By" handles all the parameters where you put interactive sort. "Sort Order" determines if it is ascending or descending. You can use these parameters to sort with in the Detail group or even in the dataset itself.

HTH.